# Maven transitive dependencies in micro-services project

Tags: java, git, maven, kotlin

I am currently working on a project on microservices architecture. It has around 100+ modules which are individual projects in different repositories on git. Few of these are runnable boot apps, while others are API and implementations, which are included as jars in runnable projects and also among each other whenever required.

Dependency graph among the modules is a mess, we are specifying all dependencies in `test` scope, many of the modules are using api from its dependency's dependency.

It is a huge task to make a release as it requires us to make all the version updates of direct and indirect dependencies in 100+ repositories.

can someone share some best practices that can simplify this mess and if there is any tool which can be used to visualize/manage transitive dependencies in a more controlled and reliable way?

Comment: Why do you have test dependencies between microservices on code level ? Microservice is the idea to have a dependency on the API level not on the code level..? Or do i misunderstand a thing? Can you describe some examples and show some example pom's ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for micro services to stay in sync with respect to transitive dependencies, and you do not deploy the full stack all at once. E.g. Each service is independent code that is independently deployable.

If you have shared code, it should be treated as an external dependency (held in a central repo like Nexus) that can be independently updated per service.

The only hard dependency that exists is the public API between the services. As an example, you may communicate between services with JSON based APIs over REST. If one of those APIs change in a not-backward compatible way, then you need to be careful about/think through deployment order.

There is no substitute for thinking through things like what an API should or should not expose, proper size and responsibility of each service, and architectural simplicity. If you get these things wrong you'll be stuck with an unmaintainable mess, regardless of if you write micro-services or a monolith.

EDIT:
Typically (when I do it) if service2 wants to call service1, it uses a REST API to communicate, and implements everything needed to talk to that API within service2 itself. E.g. There is a `RestTemplate` that is wired up, a `Service1.java` that will `@Autowire` the `RestTemplate` instance, and the POJOs modeling the request and response for service1 are directly implemented in service2. E.g. there is not a shared code dependency, there is an API contract dependency. 
As I originally mentioned, you could also go the "shared code approach" of putting the client libraries on something like Nexus, but I've personally found that to be more hassle than it's worth. A lot of the time, what I've found is that even if there are multiple callers of a particular service, the different callers actually make use of different APIs, and any given service only models the part of the API (both endpoints and subset of POJOs) that is needed/applicable. And if that happens to be the case, a shared library does not actually involve sharing as much as it obscures which service will be impacted by a specific API change.

Comment: this answers many of the points that I was facing, the only thing which still remains is, transitive dependency, like we have a service api (say service1-api.jar), which is being used as a dependency in another api (say service2-api.jar), I have, say 2 microservice apps (say spring boot apps, micro1-App which uses service1-api.jar and micro2-App which uses service2-api.jar as a direct dependency but also have service1-api.jar available as a transitive dependency and is also using it directly in its code).... This whole dependency graph is a mess...

Comment: I just explained with an example of 4 repos (2 microservice-apps and 2 service api(s)), things go out of imagination if u have hundreds os such repose interlinked... is there any way to have a better control/visibility of things in such situation?

Comment: I should also note that there will always be dependencies that need to be updated--if you update the API to service1 that breaks callers, you'll have to arrange to fix all the services that are calling service1 that are impacted, and you'll have to find a way to roll that all out without outages. But that's table stakes for micro services.